# Como abrir um arquivo .txt e jogar o texto para meu TextBox no Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá, pessoal!

Para fins de estudo, eu criei meu próprio bloco de notas personalizado, ele consegue abrir arquivos
e pegar o texto de um bloco de notas comum do Windows através do **OpenFileDialog** e
transferir para o meu programa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu quero que quando o usuário for abrir o arquivo **a partir da interface do windows,** o texto
daquele arquivo seja transferido para o meu atual, mas não sei fazer isso sem usar o OpenFileDialog.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse método acontece quando o usuário clica em "Abrir arquivo". O `abrirArquivo.FileName` me fornece o caminho e partir desse caminho posso transferir dados para o meu programa. Quero fazer a mesma coisa quando o usuário clicar em "Abrir" a partir do Windows, porém sem utilizar o OpenFileDialog.

```
private void MenuAbrirArquivo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Cria uma janela para abrir um arquivo
            var abrirArquivo = new OpenFileDialog();
            abrirArquivo.Title = "Selecione um arquivo";
            abrirArquivo.Filter = "txt file|*txt";
            abrirArquivo.RestoreDirectory = true;

            // Pega o resultado de qual botão ele clicou
            var resultado = abrirArquivo.ShowDialog();

            // User escolheu um arquivo
            if (resultado == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Cria um leitor para transferir os dados para o programa atual
                using(var leitor = new StreamReader(abrirArquivo.FileName))
                {
                    txtTexto.Text = leitor.ReadToEnd();
                }
                nomeArquivo = abrirArquivo.SafeFileName;
                path = abrirArquivo.FileName;
                SalvarModificacoes();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que configurar o windows pra sempre abrir arquivos txt usando a sua aplicação ou usar a opção "Abrir Com" e selecionar o seu executável.
Uma vez feito isso, sua aplicação tem que saber receber a informação do arquivo que foi enviado para ser aberto, isso pode ser feito resgatando os 'argumentos' passado pra aplicação no momento de acioná-la:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Provavelmente args[1] vai trazer o caminho do arquivo, a partir dai você carrega o arquivo como você faria se ele abrisse pelo contexto do OpenFileDlg.

Fazer isso em um evento do form onde executa assim que ele carrega seria o ponto ideal e obviamente você precisa verificar se retornou algum argumento, pois quando o usuário simplesmente abrir a aplicação, não terá argumentos algum.

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

if (args.Lenght > 1)
{
    AbrirArquivo(args[1]); // chamar seu método para abrir o arquivo a partir do caminho dele.
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Leandro! Passei 3 dias procurando como obter essa informação e você me ajudou muito! Agradeço de coração =D. Mas o caminho do do .txt não está em args[0], ele está em args[1].

Comment: Tem razão, fiquei na dúvida desse ponto quando respondi, o args[0] recebe o nome do exe se não me engano. Resposta atualizada!